# Copy Paste uv from one object to a different object

Tags: uv

I'm working since few days with blender. I would like to copy the uv of one object (flat object : raster image) to other objects with different mesh.

[image]

Like you can see on image, I would like to send the uv of France to all the little object of provinces. 
How can I do this ?

Comment: The UV map is values set store in vertices, not the image. If you’re trying to map a complicated vertices UV map on a simple one. It can’t be done with fewer and difference vertices, you will need to manipulate your image to fit the new UV values.

Answer (score 2):

Use a data transfer modifier to copy UV.  It's easiest if you first join the other objects; you can always separate them back out later (or even copy UV from duplicates that have been joined then re-separated.)

1. Create a data transfer modifier on the object. Set the target to the plane.
2. Enable face-corner data, then enable UV maps.  Set the mapping mode to nearest face interpolated.
3. Hit the "generate data layers" button on the modifier to create any UV maps that might not exist on the destination object.
4. Optionally, apply the modifier.

Data transfer is an awesome modifier that's great for a ton of stuff.  In the case of transferring UV maps, you'll run into problems if you try to transfer from something with multiple islands (there's no real solution to that, other than doing some manual fixup) but here, I anticipate a single island in your target.

Answer (score 0):

You could just unwrap your mesh from top view(Numpad 7) and move and resize your image in UV editor by pressing S for scale and G to grab.  Your mesh might give you some trouble when you unwrap it depending on your mesh. You might have to manually create islands using smart uv project and move them into place for each province after unwrapping.  Hope this helps.

The fundamentals of unwrapping can be found in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k&t=763s